# Extracting Nested JSON Fields and Array from Splunk Data Using spath

Tags: json, splunk

I'm trying to extract some information from nested JSON data stored in Splunk. Here's a simplified and anonymized example of the type of data I'm dealing with:

```
    {
  "functionAddress":"Function.v1/3.5.0",
  "responseTime":15,
  "httpStatus":200,
  "additionalParameters":{
    "locale":"en-US",
    "channel":"WEB",
    "accountToken":"Token1",
    "productType":"Product1",
    "primaryAccountToken":"Token1",
    "programTier":"Tier1",
    "programType":"Program1",
    "accountBalance":"3722494",
    "accountStatus":"ACTIVE",
    "relationShipStatus":"ACTIVE",
    "numberOfLinkedAccounts":14,
    "basic":true,
    "primary":true
  },
  "response":[
    {
      "status":{
        "code":"0000",
        "message":"SUCCESS"
      },
      "accountToken":"Token1",
      "accountIdentifier":"1M06093364",
      "accountStatus":"ACTIVE",
      "programCode":"Code1",
      "programTier":"Tier1",
      "tierDescription":"Tier First",
      "programType":"Program1",
      "currentBalance":{
        "currencyType":"POINTS",
        "value":3722494
      },
      "accountBalance":{
        "availableBalance":[
          {
            "type":"POINTS",
            "name":"POINTS",
            "pointCount":"3722494"
          }
        ]
      },
      "enrollmentIndicator":true,
      "redemptionIndicator":true,
      "accountAuthorized":true,
      "featureSetIdentifier":"PR",
      "relationships":[
        {
          "accountToken":"Token2",
          "primary":false,
          "status":"ACTIVE",
          "displayAccountNumber":"91115",
          "productRelationshipType":"Product2"
        },
        {
          "accountToken":"Token3",
          "primary":false,
          "status":"CANCELLED",
          "displayAccountNumber":"91016",
          "productRelationshipType":"Product3"
        },
        // more relationship objects here
      ],
      "locale":"en-US",
      "isBasic":true
    }
  ]
}
```

The response field is a JSON string that contains an array (even if there's only one element). Inside this array, there's a relationships array that can contain multiple elements.

I'm trying to extract the accountToken, accountIdentifier, accountStatus fields and all the relationships from this data into a table. So far, I've tried the following query but it doesn't seem to work as expected:

```
    index=my_index ReadAccounts relationshipStatus en-US CANCELLED
| spath input=response path={}.accountToken output=accountToken
| spath input=response path={}.accountIdentifier output=accountIdentifier
| spath input=response path={}.accountStatus output=accountStatus
| spath input=response path={}.relationships{} output=relationships
| mvexpand relationships
| rename relationships as _raw
| spath input=_raw path=accountToken output=relationship_accountToken
| spath input=_raw path=primary output=relationship_primary
| spath input=_raw path=status output=relationship_status
| spath input=_raw path=displayAccountNumber output=relationship_displayAccountNumber
| spath input=_raw path=productRelationshipType output=relationship_productRelationshipType
| table _time, message, accountToken, accountIdentifier, accountStatus, relationship_accountToken, relationship_primary, relationship_status, relationship_displayAccountNumber, relationship_productRelationshipType
| head 10
```

When I run this query, the table appears blank, except for the _time column and everything is still in message. Could someone please advise what might be going wrong and how I can correct it? I'm trying to extract each relationship as its own row in the table.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

The `mvexpand` command does nothing since 'relationships' is not a multi-value field.  Nor is it necessary to rename a field to _raw to parse JSON - just specify a different input value.

Here's my version of your query.

````
index=my_index ReadAccounts relationshipStatus en-US CANCELLED
``` Parse the whole JSON event ```
| spath path=response
| spath input=response path={}.accountToken output=accountToken
| spath input=response path={}.accountIdentifier output=accountIdentifier
| spath input=response path={}.accountStatus output=accountStatus
| spath input=response path={}.relationships{} output=relationships
| spath input=response path={}.status.message output=message
| spath input=relationships path=accountToken output=relationship_accountToken
| spath input=relationships path=primary output=relationship_primary
| spath input=relationships path=status output=relationship_status
| spath input=relationships path=displayAccountNumber output=relationship_displayAccountNumber
| spath input=relationships path=productRelationshipType output=relationship_productRelationshipType
| table _time, message, accountToken, accountIdentifier, accountStatus, relationship_accountToken, relationship_primary, relationship_status, relationship_displayAccountNumber, relationship_productRelationshipType
| head 10
````

Here's a run-anywhere version of the query.

```
    | makeresults | eval _raw="{
        \"functionAddress\": \"Function.v1/3.5.0\",
        \"responseTime\": 15,
        \"httpStatus\": 200,
        \"additionalParameters\": {
            \"locale\": \"en-US\",
            \"channel\": \"WEB\",
            \"accountToken\": \"Token1\",
            \"productType\": \"Product1\",
            \"primaryAccountToken\": \"Token1\",
            \"programTier\": \"Tier1\",
            \"programType\": \"Program1\",
            \"accountBalance\": \"3722494\",
            \"accountStatus\": \"ACTIVE\",
            \"relationShipStatus\": \"ACTIVE\",
            \"numberOfLinkedAccounts\": 14,
            \"basic\": true,
            \"primary\": true
        },
        \"response\": [{
            \"status\": {
                \"code\": \"0000\",
                \"message\": \"SUCCESS\"
            },
            \"accountToken\": \"Token1\",
            \"accountIdentifier\": \"1M06093364\",
            \"accountStatus\": \"ACTIVE\",
            \"programCode\": \"Code1\",
            \"programTier\": \"Tier1\",
            \"tierDescription\": \"Tier First\",
            \"programType\": \"Program1\",
            \"currentBalance\": {
                \"currencyType\": \"POINTS\",
                \"value\": 3722494
            },
            \"accountBalance\": {
                \"availableBalance\": [{
                    \"type\": \"POINTS\",
                    \"name\": \"POINTS\",
                    \"pointCount\": \"3722494\"
                }]
            },
            \"enrollmentIndicator\": true,
            \"redemptionIndicator\": true,
            \"accountAuthorized\": true,
            \"featureSetIdentifier\": \"PR\",
            \"relationships\": [{
                    \"accountToken\": \"Token2\",
                    \"primary\": false,
                    \"status\": \"ACTIVE\",
                    \"displayAccountNumber\": \"91115\",
                    \"productRelationshipType\": \"Product2\"
                },
                {
                    \"accountToken\": \"Token3\",
                    \"primary\": false,
                    \"status\": \"CANCELLED\",
                    \"displayAccountNumber\": \"91016\",
                    \"productRelationshipType\": \"Product3\"
                }
            ],
            \"locale\": \"en-US\",
            \"isBasic\": true
        }]
    }"
| spath 
| spath path=response{}.relationships{}.accountToken output=relationship_accountToken
| spath path=response{}.relationships{}.primary output=relationship_primary
| spath path=response{}.relationships{}.status output=relationship_status
| spath path=response{}.relationships{}.displayAccountNumber output=relationship_displayAccountNumber
| spath path=response{}.relationships{}.productRelationshipType output=relationship_productRelationshipType
| spath path=response{}.accountIdentifier output=accountIdentifier
| spath path=response{}.accountStatus output=accountStatus
| spath path=response{}.accountToken output=accountToken
| spath path=response{}.status.message output=message
| table _time, message, accountToken, accountIdentifier, accountStatus, relationship_accountToken, relationship_primary, relationship_status, relationship_displayAccountNumber, relationship_productRelationshipType
```

Comment: nope still everything (the event) is ONLY appearing in 'message' and I get Field 'relationships' does not exist in the data or if you can share the link for runanywhere too

Comment: I forgot to mention that the message is the base JSON, updated post above

 message {

Comment: The new event is not valid JSON so Splunk won't parse it.

Comment: RichG, I have updated the JSON event, please take a look and update your query

Comment: I can post another question if this reply is too complicated, but I can accept your solution if this works